docker-php-ext-install recently failing in a php7.1-fpm image
Im having some issues recently .. About 3 days ago my installs just docker setup is failing each time im running it ... Its been working perfect before this, unfortauntly due to work, im unable to upgrade from PHP 7.1
In my dockerfile i have the following line to install some modules RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql zip bcmath opcache
Im sorry about the output as its quite large, but im hoping someone can shed some light oon whats going on;
1.223 Configuring for:
1.223 PHP Api Version:         20160303
1.223 Zend Module Api No:      20160303
1.223 Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
3.315 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
3.326 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
3.341 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
3.554 checking for cc... cc
3.719 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
4.020 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
4.029 checking for suffix of executables...
4.278 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
4.595 checking for suffix of object files... o
4.802 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
4.998 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
5.206 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
5.539 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
5.914 checking for icc... no
5.980 checking for suncc... no
6.045 checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
6.372 checking for system library directory... lib
6.372 checking if compiler supports -R... no
6.473 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
6.833 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
6.918 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
6.918 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
7.211 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
7.211 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
7.211 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
7.211 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
7.211 checking if debug is enabled... no
7.309 checking if zts is enabled... no
7.402 checking for re2c... re2c
7.403 checking for re2c version... 1.1.1 (ok)
7.432 checking for gawk... no
7.432 checking for nawk... nawk
7.433 checking if nawk is broken... no
7.442 checking for mcrypt support... yes, shared
7.443 checking for libmcrypt version... >= 2.5.6
7.528 checking for mcrypt_module_open in -lmcrypt... no
7.854 checking for mcrypt_module_open in -lmcrypt... yes
8.186 checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
8.214 checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
8.228 checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
8.228 checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
8.241 checking whether ln -s works... yes
8.241 checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
8.346 checking for ANSI C header files... yes
9.128 checking for sys/types.h... yes
9.315 checking for sys/stat.h... yes
9.510 checking for stdlib.h... yes
9.707 checking for string.h... yes
9.904 checking for memory.h... yes
10.10 checking for strings.h... yes
10.28 checking for inttypes.h... yes
10.48 checking for stdint.h... yes
10.68 checking for unistd.h... yes
10.86 checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
11.02 checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
11.09 checking for dlfcn.h... yes
11.10 checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
11.13 checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
11.67 checking for objdir... .libs
11.69 checking for ar... ar
11.69 checking for ranlib... ranlib
11.69 checking for strip... strip
12.05 checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
12.21 checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
12.22 checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
12.36 checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
12.68 checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
12.89 checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
12.97 checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
13.14 checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
13.25 checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
13.25 checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
13.26 checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
13.26 checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
13.26 checking whether to build static libraries... no
14.50
14.50 creating libtool
14.63 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
14.99 configure: creating ./config.status
15.43 config.status: creating config.h
15.63 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/libtool --mode=compile cc -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.c -o mcrypt.lo
16.38 mkdir .libs
16.40  cc -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/mcrypt.o
17.19 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/libtool --mode=compile cc -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt_filter.c -o mcrypt_filter.lo
17.94  cc -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt_filter.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/mcrypt_filter.o
18.46 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie -o mcrypt.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/modules  mcrypt.lo mcrypt_filter.lo -lmcrypt
19.33 cc -shared  .libs/mcrypt.o .libs/mcrypt_filter.o  /usr/lib/libmcrypt.so  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,-soname -Wl,mcrypt.so -o .libs/mcrypt.so
19.40 creating mcrypt.la
19.48 /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/libtool: line 6038:  1925 Illegal instruction     $rm $output
19.48 (cd .libs && rm -f mcrypt.la && ln -s ../mcrypt.la mcrypt.la)
19.50 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/libtool --mode=install cp ./mcrypt.la /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/modules
19.69 cp ./.libs/mcrypt.so /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/modules/mcrypt.so
19.72 cp ./.libs/mcrypt.lai /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/modules/mcrypt.la
19.80 PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt/modules
19.82 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
...

19.86
19.87 Build complete.
19.89 Don't forget to run 'make test'.
19.91
20.00 + strip --strip-all modules/mcrypt.so
20.18 Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/
20.63 find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
20.67 find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
20.71 find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
20.75 find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
20.80 find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
20.84 rm -f libphp.la       modules/* libs/*
20.99 Illegal instruction
21.04 Configuring for:
21.04 PHP Api Version:
21.04 Zend Module Api No:      20160303
21.04 Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
22.99 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
23.01 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
23.02 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
23.24 checking for cc... cc
23.40 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
23.65 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
23.66 checking for suffix of executables...
23.92 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
24.25 checking for suffix of object files... o
24.46 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
24.66 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
24.87 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
25.22 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
25.59 checking for icc... no
25.66 checking for suncc... no
25.73 checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
26.05 checking for system library directory... lib
26.05 checking if compiler supports -R... no
26.15 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
26.49 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
26.56 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
26.56 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
26.84 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
26.84 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
26.84 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
26.84 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
26.84 checking if debug is enabled... no
26.94 checking if zts is enabled... no
27.04 checking for re2c... re2c
27.04 checking for re2c version... 1.1.1 (ok)
27.06 checking for gawk... no
27.06 checking for nawk... nawk
27.06 checking if nawk is broken... no
27.07 checking for MySQL support for PDO... yes, shared
27.07 checking for the location of libz... no
27.08 checking for MySQL UNIX socket location...
27.08 checking for PDO includes... checking for PDO includes... /usr/local/include/php/ext
27.15 checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
27.18 checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
27.20 checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
27.20 checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
27.21 checking whether ln -s works... yes
27.21 checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
27.33 checking for ANSI C header files... yes
28.14 checking for sys/types.h... yes
28.32 checking for sys/stat.h... yes
28.50 checking for stdlib.h... yes
28.67 checking for string.h... yes
28.85 checking for memory.h... yes
29.03 checking for strings.h... yes
29.21 checking for inttypes.h... yes
29.39 checking for stdint.h... yes
29.57 checking for unistd.h... yes
29.74 checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
29.88 checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
29.95 checking for dlfcn.h... yes
29.96 checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
29.98 checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
30.49 checking for objdir... .libs
30.52 checking for ar... ar
30.52 checking for ranlib... ranlib
30.52 checking for strip... strip
30.87 checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
31.03 checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
31.03 checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
31.18 checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
31.48 checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
31.70 checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
31.78 checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
31.94 checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
32.06 checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
32.06 checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
32.07 checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
32.07 checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
32.07 checking whether to build static libraries... no
33.27
33.27 creating libtool
33.39 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
33.76 configure: creating ./config.status
34.20 config.status: creating config.h
34.39 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c -o pdo_mysql.lo
35.18 mkdir .libs
35.20  cc -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_mysql.o
35.66 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c -o mysql_driver.lo
36.43  cc -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/mysql_driver.o
37.09 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c -o mysql_statement.lo
37.87  cc -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/mysql_statement.o
38.47 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie -o pdo_mysql.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules  pdo_mysql.lo mysql_driver.lo mysql_statement.lo
39.29 cc -shared  .libs/pdo_mysql.o .libs/mysql_driver.o .libs/mysql_statement.o   -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,-soname -Wl,pdo_mysql.so -o .libs/pdo_mysql.so
39.36 creating pdo_mysql.la
39.41 (cd .libs && rm -f pdo_mysql.la && ln -s ../pdo_mysql.la pdo_mysql.la)
39.43 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/libtool --mode=install cp ./pdo_mysql.la /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules
39.62 cp ./.libs/pdo_mysql.so /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules/pdo_mysql.so
39.65 cp ./.libs/pdo_mysql.lai /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules/pdo_mysql.la
39.73 PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules
39.75 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
39.75 Libraries have been installed in:
39.75    /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules
39.75
39.75 If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
39.75 in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
39.75 specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
39.75 flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
39.75    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
39.75      during execution
39.75    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
39.75      during linking
39.75    - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
39.75    - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
39.75
39.75 See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
39.75 more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
39.77 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
39.79
39.80 Build complete.
39.82 Don't forget to run 'make test'.
39.84
39.91 + strip --strip-all modules/pdo_mysql.so
40.08 Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/
40.54 find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
40.58 find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
40.62 find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
40.66 find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
40.70 find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
40.75 rm -f libphp.la       modules/* libs/*
40.95 Configuring for:
40.95 PHP Api Version:         20160303
40.95 Zend Module Api No:      20160303
40.95 Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
42.97 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
42.98 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
43.00 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
43.23 checking for cc... cc
43.40 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
43.67 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
43.68 checking for suffix of executables...
43.95 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
44.28 checking for suffix of object files... o
44.49 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
44.68 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
44.89 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
45.22 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
45.56 checking for icc... no
45.62 checking for suncc... no
45.68 checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
46.00 checking for system library directory... lib
46.00 checking if compiler supports -R... no
46.11 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
46.46 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
46.54 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
46.54 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
46.83 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
46.83 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
46.83 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
46.83 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
46.83 checking if debug is enabled... no
46.93 checking if zts is enabled... no
47.03 checking for re2c... re2c
47.03 checking for re2c version... 1.1.1 (ok)
47.05 checking for gawk... no
47.05 checking for nawk... nawk
47.05 checking if nawk is broken... no
47.06 checking for zip archive read/writesupport... yes, shared
47.06 checking for the location of libz... no
47.06 checking pcre install prefix... no
47.06 checking libzip... no
47.07 checking for the location of zlib... /usr
48.18 checking for ANSI C header files... yes
48.96 checking for sys/types.h... yes
49.14 checking for sys/stat.h... yes
49.31 checking for stdlib.h... yes
49.49 checking for string.h... yes
49.67 checking for memory.h... yes
49.86 checking for strings.h... yes
50.05 checking for inttypes.h... yes
50.25 checking for stdint.h... yes
50.44 checking for unistd.h... yes
50.62 checking stdbool.h usability... yes
50.78 checking stdbool.h presence... yes
50.84 checking for stdbool.h... yes
50.85 checking fts.h usability... yes
51.00 checking fts.h presence... yes
51.07 checking for fts.h... yes
51.08 checking for int8_t... yes
51.51 checking for int16_t... yes
51.92 checking for int32_t... yes
52.33 checking for int64_t... yes
52.74 checking for uint8_t... yes
53.15 checking for uint16_t... yes
53.60 checking for uint32_t... yes
54.04 checking for uint64_t... yes
54.48 checking for ssize_t... yes
54.92 checking size of short... 2
55.30 checking size of int... 4
55.67 checking size of long... 8
56.05 checking size of long long... 8
56.44 checking size of off_t... 8
56.84 checking size of size_t... 8
57.24 checking for touch... /usr/bin/touch
57.24 checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
57.24 checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
57.47 checking for struct tm.tm_zone... yes
57.71 checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
57.74 checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
57.75 checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
57.75 checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
57.76 checking whether ln -s works... yes
57.76 checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
57.87 checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
58.01 checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
58.07 checking for dlfcn.h... yes
58.08 checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
58.11 checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
58.62 checking for objdir... .libs
58.64 checking for ar... ar
58.64 checking for ranlib... ranlib
58.64 checking for strip... strip
59.00 checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
59.16 checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
59.16 checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
59.31 checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
59.63 checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
59.87 checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
59.95 checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
60.14 checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
60.25 checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
60.25 checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
60.27 checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
60.27 checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
60.27 checking whether to build static libraries... no
61.53
61.53 creating libtool
61.65 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
62.03 configure: creating ./config.status
62.46 config.status: creating config.h
62.66 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/zip/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c /usr/src/php/ext/zip/php_zip.c -o php_zip.lo
63.42 mkdir .libs
63.44  cc -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c /usr/src/php/ext/zip/php_zip.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_zip.o
64.35 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/zip/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c /usr/src/php/ext/zip/zip_stream.c -o zip_stream.lo
65.05  cc -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/src/php/ext/zip/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 "" /usr/src/php/ext/zip/zip_stream.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/zip_stream.o
65.06 cc: error: : No such file or directory
65.06 make: *** [Makefile:196: zip_stream.lo] Error 1
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql zip bcmath opcache" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

The following is a snippet of the Dockerfile which im allowed to post;
FROM php:7.1-fpm

# Software installation
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libfontconfig \
        libfreetype6 \
        libxrender1 \
        libxext6 \
        libx11-6 \
        libmaxminddb0 \
        libmaxminddb-dev \
        libgmp-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        mmdb-bin \
        libzip-dev \
        git \
        zip \
        unzip; \
    # Cleanup \
    apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install required PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql zip bcmath opcache

RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
RUN pecl install redis-5.3.7; \
    docker-php-ext-enable redis.so


Please share the Dockerfile with relevant lines. This error may come from the fact that PHP 7.1 is old now, and repositories may not be available anymore.

@A.L-saynotoAI ... I had to truncate some of the error output as  it wouldnt let me post that much, but the part of the Dockerfile is now atttached

There is no such image php7.1-fpm on dockerhub. If changed to php:7.1-fpm the shown Dockerfile builds without errors.

Sorry ....  My bad, it is php:7.1-fpm
